# python thread join not happening properly

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()
class Worker( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, q ):
        threading.Thread.__init__( self )
        self.q = q

    def run( self ):
        while True:
            print '%s waiting for data' % self.getName()
            data = self.q.get()
            print '%s data fetched from queue %s' % ( self.getName(), data )
            if data == 'shutdown':
                print '%s shutting down in %s' % ( self.getName(), self )
                return
            print '%s received a message: %s' % ( self.getName(), data )

    def stop( self ):
        self.q.put( "shutdown" )

#        self.join()  # If I uncomment this line, then sometimes the program does not complete.


def broadcast_event( data ):
    q.put( data )

t1 = Worker( q )
t2 = Worker( q )
t1.start()
t2.start()
broadcast_event( "first event" )
broadcast_event( "second event" )

t1.stop()
t2.stop()
```

I'm trying to understand threads in python and I'm stuck in the multithreaded queue example.
What I'm trying to do:-

1. Create 2 threads using a single queue object
2. Now, I put 2 different data entries in the queue (using `broadcast_event` function)
3. Now, in the stop method, there is a commented line where I'm joining the thread back to the main program.

But, when I uncomment the `self.join` line, the program hangs up and runs forever. However, if I remove the `self.join`, it works perfectly.

I want to understand if there is a problem how I'm trying to make use of join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is that both threads use the same queue. Deadlock scenario is:

1. main thread sends `'shutdown'` in `t1.stop()`
2. `t2` reads `'shutdown'` from `q`
3. main thread joins `t1`, which is waiting forever for new messages.

You can solve this by making 2 queues or doing first two `shutdown` messages and then two joins.

Comment: So, does t2.stop get called?

Comment: @GodMan, it does not. Main thread never returns from `t1.join()`, since it never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two threads using one queue.  When you `put` a message in the queue, you can't tell which of the threads will *consume* it.  When you call `stop()`, adding `"shutdown"` to the queue, it may be consumed by any of the threads, not necessarily the one you intend.

The result can be that another thread is quitting, and you're `join`ing the wrong one.

A possible solution is to first put `shutdown` in the queue N times (N = number of threads), and then join them all.

```
for i in range(N):
  q.put("shutdown")
for t in threads:
  t.join()
```

A better, more robust solution, would be to avoid passing the shutdown message through the queue.  You can use a `self.should_stop` attribute for that, checking this attribute periodically in `run`.

Comment: but, if I'm doing self.join, how can I be joining the wrong one?

Comment: the problem is not with calling `join`, it is with putting `shutdown` in the queue. the shutdown-request can reach the wrong thread (not `self`)